# Is there a way to get simple XML child elements by node name?

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

In PHP, is there an existing method to get one or more child elements by node name (recursively) or would you have to write a function for that yourself?

For example, this is my XML:

```
<parent>
    <child>
        <grandchild>Jan</grandchild>
        <grandchild>Kees</grandchild>
    </child>
</parent>
```

And I'm looking for a method that returns something like:
    Array(
       [0] => 'Jan',
       [1] => 'Kees'
    )

by means of calling something like:

```
$grandchildren = $xml->children('grandchild');
```

The above does exist according to documentation but only for namespaces.

e: The accepted answer below worked. This is what I ran to test it.

```
$xml = '
    <parent>
        <child>
            <grandchild>Jan</grandchild>
            <grandchild>Kees</grandchild>
        </child>
    </parent>';

$L_o_xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

$L_o_child = $L_o_xml->xpath('//grandchild');

foreach( $L_o_child as $hi ){
   print "\n".(string)$hi;
}
```

Simply printed:

```
Jan
Kees
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`$xml->xpath()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) to select nodes in a variety of complex ways:

```
$xml->xpath('//grandchild');   // select all  grandchild  elements in the document
```

Comment: Thanks, just tried this. I var dumped it and I can see that it does return an array with two objects, but not the value. Can you elaborate if there's a way to get the values of the elements?

Comment: @vanamerongen Just iterate through the elements and cast each to a `string` to get their values.

Comment: perhaps `$xml->xpath('//grandchild/text()')`

Comment: @JJoao That would only work under the assumption that the `grandchild` elements contain one text node and nothing else.